# Is it better to change a background image on a responsive site with javascript or css with media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, responsive

Working within the confines of our very large scale cms we have come across several instances where we need to set the background images of certain divs from within a content item for maintenance purposes. What this means is we can not put the background-image elements into the main css. There are 2 versions of every background image - mobile and desktop. The solutions we can do are either to write a  block into the page and put the css there using @media queries, or to add the background image paths into data-background-sm/ data-background-lg attributes and use javascript to swap them at breakpoints.

What are peoples opinion on which is faster/better/more 'acceptable'?

Comment: Generally I would recommend going the CSS route when it comes to layout

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using media queries in this case, especially with your focus on responsiveness. They will allow specific rules to be loaded per your varied elements (hereby background images, etc.)

> When a media query is true, the corresponding style sheet or style rules are applied, following the normal cascading rules. Style sheets with media queries attached to their  tags will still download even if their media queries would return false (they will not apply, however).
>
> Unless you use the not or only operators, the media type is optional and the all type will be implied.

See more about using media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

However, if you are quite adept with JavaScript and would prefer that route, I would suggest using tools like WebPack, a module bundler. It enables your assets to become modules so that you can load each one specifically only when needed. For a great explanation on its use, see here: https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/

Answer (score 1):

The best choice would be to use @media queries.

You should always use CSS over Javascript when it comes to styling your page, unless you have no choice.

I can't help you concerning the performance, but I doubt that there's a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Javascript approach seems cleaner for this use case.